# How can i burn bigger audio tracks

Tags: installation, burning

I'm trying to burn 20hr until 30 hr mp3 tracks. Is there any software which can do that?

Note: that i have bought cd's which are 30/70 hrs long and i'm trying to burn some mp3 tracks on audio cd's.

Comment: 30/70 hour CDs? Can you give a link to these? AFAIK most CDs are limited to 80minutes PCM at the very most.

Comment: Do you mean 30 / 70 *minutes*? Because that roughly corresponds with the capacity of mini / standard audio CDs.

Comment: No not 80mins,i mean hours because i bought some cd's from shop with long hours.

Answer (score 2):

Audio CDs (that is, ones conforming to the Red Book standard) use uncompressed Linear PCM for their data so take up huge swathes of space on a compact disc. Some are extended (thinner spindles, more outer tracks) but these improvements give minutes extra.

The limits for audio on CD are just under 80 minutes. Their bitrate is 1411kbps.

If you put compressed audio on a CD as data, you can change things around. You can use something like the Speex codec to get things down to just 4kbps if you wanted to. With that you could fit 450-470 hours* on a data CD.

The *only* problem is you're limited to where you can play this disc. Any player will need to know the Speex coded so almost all CD players (eg Hi-Fis) are going to struggle. You'll most likely need to play the disc through a computer.

If this is no good, you could look at low-bitrate MP3 (16-48kbps VBR - any lower will be horrible) and you'll only get ~50 hours per disc *but* a lot more hardware CD players support MP3 tracks. That has been an increasingly common feature in them for some years.

<sub>* There's going to be a bit of overhead from the file format but it'll be a hell of a lot more than 80 minutes or 80 hours.</sub>

Comment: Is there any program for linux like that you mentioned.